# GWT Internationalization --- <ui:msg> eating spaces

Tags: gwt, internationalization, uibinder

I have been working on an internationalization project recently in which I utilized the GWT i18n module. Everything worked fine until I hit this problem.

Below is a line in my UiBinder xml, as you can see there's a trailing space there.

```
<ui:msg>Click here </ui:msg>
```

However, the corresponding entry inside the auto-generated properties file becomes

```
936CCDB97115E9F35A11D35E3D5B5CAD=Click here<line break>
```

The space at the end is missing! 
I take a look of the generated transient files, it's missing there as well.

Following is the attributes I used in the xml header

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
ui:generateFormat="com.google.gwt.i18n.rebind.format.PropertiesFormat"
ui:generateKeys="com.google.gwt.i18n.rebind.keygen.MD5KeyGenerator"
ui:generateLocales="default"
    ......>
```

Any Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but I believe that you could use an a nonbreaking space entity.

```
&#160;
```

Comment: Actually using the &nbsp; in the original url text doesn't help, it seems to be ignored by GWT when processing it. So in the end I got to append it after the generated entries.